# Is the Generalized Dirichlet Distribution an Exponential Family?

Tags: exponential-family, generalized-dirichlet-distribution

Is the [Generalized Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Dirichlet_distribution) an exponential family?  If so, what is its log-normalizer, sufficient statistics, and carrier measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is an exponential family.

It has sufficient statistics: $\{\log(x_i)\}_i$ and $\{\log(1 - \sum_{j \le i}x_j)\}_i$.

It has zero carrier measure.

Its log-normalizer is $\sum_i B(\alpha_i, \beta_i)$ where the natural parameters that correspond to the above sufficient statistics are $\{\alpha_i-1\}_i$ and $\{\gamma_i\}_i$ with $\gamma_j=\beta_j-\alpha_{j+1}-\beta_{j+1}$.

After some work, I was able to implement the distribution [here](https://github.com/NeilGirdhar/efax/blob/main/efax/_src/distributions/gen_dirichlet.py).